# Python - How to add column headers from the generated List

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, arcpy

In the code I have generated a list of column headers.

Examples:

```
fList = [] 
fields = arcpy.ListFields(table)
fList.append(field.name)

print(fList)

#[u'A', u'B', u'C', u'D', u'E']
```

Separately created numpy array:

```
matrix = np.array(values_from_list_values)

print(matrix)

[[  2.  45.  32.   9.   2.]
 [  6.  32.   2.  25.   5.]
 [  7.  25.   6.  12.   7.]
 [  8.  12.   5.  32.   8.]
 [  9.  19.   7.  15.   9.]]
```

Number of columns in the two lists is always equal. Also, the order of columns is always equal.

Is there a possibility that the generated list column headers are added to the matrix? And in what way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I`m not getting what your requirement exactly, may be you want to add the list in 'fList' as an header to 'matrix', if it is so, you can do it simply as -

```
matrix = np.insert(matrix,0,flist,0)
```

Please accept the answer or elaborate your requirement more.

Comment: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'insert'

Comment: Try - **matrix = np.insert(matrix,0,flist,0)**

Comment: A, OK.. matrix--- tolist() and flist --- tolist(). Now working ... Tnx @Bot-13

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with ArcMap, version 10.1 or greater, check out [TableToNumpyArray](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/heLP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#/TableToNumPyArray/018w00000018000000/) in the arcpy.da (data access module)  There are similar functions to convert to and from tables and feature class datasets.  A numpy ndarray (recarray) or a masked arrays is created depending upon whether you have nodata values in your table..  You can also bring in geometry object representation as points if you need to work with geometry

Comment: I tried ... but when I switch a table using TableToNumpyArray then I have a problem with the calculations array. I assume that the problem is a string in the column headers ... I do not know how to solve ...

Comment: Field names should comply with shapefile specs  ... less than 10 characters, can't begin with a number, no spaces and no other characters as letters, numbers and the underscore.